# Confused about Python installations, module installation, and interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

So yesterday I had to create a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) in order to be able to install Python modules that wouldn't install thanks to OS X El Capitan's new SIP. I thought I did everything right, but today I'm reaching a different conclusion. I hope I can be clear about it.

my python custom install is at myname/learnp/imdb_module, this is where I created it with virtualenv. Edit: I later moved it to myname/learnp/ayr2/imdb_module.

However, when I try to run the interpreter, it seems to always default to the Python that is in Library or something along these lines. I found out about this because a certain module that I managed to install in this custom python env wouldn't import, when I checked what modules I have, it wasn't the same as what I expected.

Furthermore, it seems that ALL other modules that I wanted to install on the CUSTOM virtualenv were installed on the main python env, and that I wasn't installing those modules on the custom env all along.

Excuse me, but I'm very confused right now.

- I know how to create a virtual env
- I know how to activate it (it appears to the right on Terminal line)
- I don't know how to install modules to my virtual env
- I don't know how to make the interpreter run from the virtual env so I can do python operations that are only possible by using custom env modules

Any advice is much appreciated!

**Update:**

Followed [Will Hogan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33513297/5013234) for troubleshooting,and I think something weird is happening, quoting my comment to his answer:

> HI, thanks for taking the time to answer. This is basically the way I understood this. However, let me attach a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK5U8.jpg . Am I right to assume something is wrong here? My prompt is changed with the virtualenv named "imdb_module", but when I type in `which python` it doesn't list `ayr2/imdb_module/bin` but rather a folder with the path `usr/bin/python`, which if I understand correctly is the "default" environment.
>
> And not if this helps in any way, but `echo $PATH` when (imdv_module) appears to the right of the prompt, gives this (I redacted my name): `/Users/REDACTEDNAME/learnp/imdb_module/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: Just use `pip install module_name` once the virtualenv is active. If the virtualenv is active, it should set the Python interpreter to the copy inside your virtual environment.

Comment: i would advise use to go into the env and run the command and bring the output here...however the most common problem i get is to install some module in virtual env using sudo...it can only run with sudo/admin but this not the purpose of virtual env...note that virtualenv also leverage available system library

Comment: The problem is most likely that you're not calling the virtual environment's python interpreter. I'm on mobile, so I can't find a good resource to point you to, but Google how to build a flask app with Python and find an article that talks about doing it in a virtual environment. Those articles will demonstrate how to call python from your virtual environment.

Comment: @brittenb thanks, I have Googled. Actually this came while I was working on a Flask project. The thing is, the author opposes activating the virtual env and instead talks about "she-bang" and including this "!#PATH" that I don't really understand.

Comment: @zerohedge Here is the article I had in mind when I made my comment: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world About a quarter of the way down the page you'll see where he starts talking about how to install packages and you'll see that he recommends using `flask/bin/pip install {package_name}` where flask is the name of the virtual environment and would need to be changed to fit your situation. Will Hogan's solution below gives a couple other workable solutions, including activating the virtual environment. Hope that helps.

Comment: @brittenb funny, that's exactly the guide I followed — but something seems seriously wrong with my install. Look at my question's update and my comment to Will Hogan's answer. Am I wrong to assume something's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While creating the virtualenv you should see it installing setuptools and pip:

```
$ virtualenv testvenv
New python executable in testvenv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in testvenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

After ensuring the virtualenv is activated you should see your prompt change:

```
$ . ./testvenv/bin/activate
(testvenv)$
```

Now you can confirm the paths to python and pip, which should be in the virtualenv:

```
(testvenv)$ which python
/private/tmp/testvenv/bin/python
(testvenv)$ which pip
/private/tmp/testvenv/bin/pip
```

If you aren't seeing the python and pip locations as being under the virtualenv's directory, then the virtualenv has not been activated.

I would also ensure that, if you're executing the .py file directly (and not with "`python foo.py`"), that your shebang line uses:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Or even the full path to the virtualenv's `python`, e.g.:

```
#!/tmp/testvenv/bin/python
```

As opposed to, say:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

The first will search in the current environment, which will be set by the virtualenv activation. The second explicitly points to the virtualenv's `python'.

Comment: HI, thanks for taking the time to answer. This is basically the way I understood this. However, let me attach a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/DfpngJq.jpg . Am I right to assume something is wrong here? My prompt is changed with the virtualenv named "imdb_module", but when I type in `which python` it doesn't list `ayr2/imdb_module/bin` but rather a folder with the path `usr/bin/python`, which if I understand correctly is the "default" environment.

Comment: And not if this helps in any way, but `echo $PATH` when (imdv_module) appears to the right of the prompt, gives this (I redacted my name): `/Users/REDACTEDNAME/learnp/imdb_module/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: Right, `/usr/bin/python` is the system-level Python interpreter. Activating the virtualenv (among other things)  puts the virtualenv's ./bin directory first in your `PATH`. Are you using a Bash shell?

Comment: I'm using Terminal, not even sure what a Bash shell is. And I don't really understand if my screenshot shows that something *is* wrong or not. Sorry if I'm being slow.

Comment: That's OK, I see from your last comment that it's actually correctly setting the `PATH` but "something else" is wrong, if you `ls -l $HOME/learnp/imdb_module/bin` is `python` owned by your user and executable?

Comment: Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/kyEkKTBg See I'm sure there's something wrong because there should be several Flask related modules installed there and now I know I may have messed my system Python by installing all this stuff there instead of this one.

Comment: wait a minute. when I echo $PATH, there's a directory missing there! I moved the `imdb_module` direcotry from  `learnp` to 'learnp/ayr2'…could that be the culprit?

Comment: I was going to ask about why they were different but thought perhaps you'd created another virtualenv :) Yes, that will do it, the full path to the virtualenv is baked into the activate script.

Comment: What can I do in this case? I'd really like to keep this environment and when it finally works install some more modules! (also: so where have all those modules installed when I `pip`ed them?

Comment: That's a little messy. You could change the value of the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable in `activate` to match where you've moved this, but `pip` and `setuptools` will also have this path referenced in their shebang lines so you'd need to modify that for those as well. Assuming you installed with the virtualenv's `pip`, the modules will be in the  `lib` subdirectory of the virtualenv. In general you probably want to work with a "requirements file" with `pip` to make it easy to recreate environments, per http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/.

Comment: That is way above my skills for now. I also tried to run `- - recolatble` and it threw in a bunch of errors. So just delete the imdb_module folder in Finder and re-create the env, and then re-install all packages..?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's best to recreate. If you want a simple way to get back the modules list you can move the virtualenv back to its original location and run `pip freeze`.

Comment: Ok. Last question since this is getting lengthy, can I then use this list (I have it) to auto-install those packages to my new venv?

Comment: Yeah, if you `pip freeze > requirements.txt` you can then install from the requirements file with `pip install -r requirements.txt` install from the list.

Comment: providing the full path in the second command, yeah? Otherwise pip can't locate the file right?

Comment: That's correct. You could copy the file to your project directory base. It's customary to keep it with your project in this manner.